# Block third party HTTPS referers in Nginx

Tags: nginx, http-referer

I've a mp3 download site. Some websites are using my site's feed, that's why I am loosing my limited Bandwidth.

I've used the following code to restrict access to my mp3 files from third-party referers.

```
valid_referers none blocked server_names *.example.com;
if ($invalid_referer) {
    return   403;
}
```

This works well for **HTTP** sites (e.g. http://www.example.com), but doesn't work at all with **HTTPS** sites (e.g. https://example.blogspot.com). Why is that and how can I block those?

Comment: Do you see in your access log the referer for the HTTPS site?

Comment: Hello @Aleks,
I know the site name and have checked by downloading files from that site, it works. Downloading can not be blocked because the site using **HTTPS**, where I've blocked all others non-https sites.

Comment: Sorry I don not understand your answer. My question was: Do you see the https domain in the access log column $http_referer? What do you see in YOUR access log when you download the file FROM that site? btw. what's the output of nginx -v and nginx -t ?